# incorrect syntax near 'T00:'

Tags: sql, datetime, iso

In one table (ExchangeRates) I've got date like 'dd.MM.yyyy' but in other table date is in iso datetime so when I try compare in where clause get an error 'incorrenct syntax near 'T00:'. Got same error when I tried to

```
convert(date, date_field_with_isotime, 104)

select top 1 * 
from ExchangeRates 
where ExchangeDate = dateadd(day, date_field_with_isotime, -1)
```

Comment: Why are you storing *strings* when apparently what you actually need to store are *datetimes*? Most databases have suitable types for storing datetimes which then mean that you don't run into *string* formatting issues.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Could you share some data from ExchangeRates table?

Comment: what if `where ExchangeDate = dateadd(day, convert(date, date_field_with_isotime, 104), -1)`

Comment: Sounds like your ISO field uses the letter `T` to separate the date and time portions. If that is the case, try using 126 or 127 instead of 104 or -1.

Comment: And I think the order for `dateadd` is the following `dateadd(day, -1, date_field_with_isotime)`.

Comment: The ISO 8601 date format is YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. When it comes to date/time many of them are far from ANSI/ISO SQL compliant.

Answer (score 0):

let's assume to your data is these

```
date_field_with_isotime        ExchangeDate
(varhcar, ISO 8601 formatted)  (date)  
2017-11-20                     19/11/2017 00:00:00
2017-11-19                     19/11/2017 00:00:00
2017-11-18                     19/11/2017 00:00:00
```

The query should be like this:

```
select top 1 * 
from dbo.ExchangeRates
where ExchangeDate = dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, date_field_with_isotime, 120))
```

But still the "TOO:" statement is strange, **check if the table has triggers.**